# linux: access to specific DDR DIMMs

Tags: linux, kernel

My x86 server contains 196GB of RAM (6 DIMMs)

Is it possible to make sure that dma_alloc_coherent will be allocated in a specified physical address ?

I want to specify the physical destination of DMA from PCIe to RAM.

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: According to a Linux export there is only one not elegant solution:
Use "mem=.." to exclude a specified amount of physical RAM. 
Then, in the kernel module, call "ioremap" to map the physical start address of this area.